# DataNucleus, HBase, JDO: "A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified"

Tags: java, hbase, jdo, datanucleus

I'm getting an exception ("A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified") when trying to follow the [DataNucleus HBase tutorial](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/guides/jdo/tutorial_hbase.html).

My datanucleus.properties file (below) doesn't specify such a property, but then nor does the tutorial, and nor does the [DataNucleus HBase sample](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datanucleus/files/datanucleus-samples/3.1/).

Edited after finding the 3.1 sample:

**src/main/resources/datanucleus.properties**

```
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=hbase:hx1:60010
javax.jdo.option.Mapping=hbase

datanucleus.metadata.validate=false
datanucleus.autoCreateSchema=true
datanucleus.validateTables=false
datanucleus.validateConstraints=false
```

**src/main/java/hbase-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration> 
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>hx1:2181</value>
    <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.
    </description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**src/main/com.business.model/package-hbase.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE orm PUBLIC 
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Java Data Objects Metadata 2.0//EN" 
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/orm_2_0.dtd">
<orm>
    <package name="com.business.model">
        <class name="Recommendation" table="Recommendations">
            <field name="id" column="ID"/>
            <field name="documents" column="DOCUMENTS"/>
        </class>

        <class name="Document">
            <field name="id" column="ID"/>
            <field name="title" column="TITLE"/>
        </class>
    </package>
</orm>
```

Any ideas what I'm missing? I'm new to JDO after having worked with JPA for a few years.

Comment: you refer to v3.0 of a deprecated sample, and v3.1 of the tutorial. I'd fix that.

Comment: I've copied the 3.1 sample, and still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: When I download the 3.1 sample, uncomment the HBase bits in "pom.xml" and "datanucleus.properties" and run it as per the tutorial it works fine (you may have to update the version of hadoop-core,hbase,zookeeper to something more recent due to their dependency issues). You only need "javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass" when you have multiple JDO implementations in your classpath (and running via the tutorial README only brings in DataNucleus), otherwise it recognises the implementation from a services file in the datanucleus-api-jdo.jar

Comment: FYI the schema generation fails if there is a space in the path to the `datanucleus.properties` file.

Comment: The example doesn't work for me: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor.setCompressionType. I can't understand why, the HBase version is `0.90.4` as per the POM, and I can't see any other versions being pulled in on the classpath?

Comment: and as said on the DN forum, and above here, _you may have to update the version of hadoop-core,hbase,zookeeper to something more recent due to their dependency issues_

Answer (score 6):

I never tried a HBase tutorial but you have to have javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass property defined. Mine is defined in persistence.xml file (src/main/resources). Property definition:

```
<property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
            value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory" />
```

You can also define this property when creating PMF.

More details are at: http://db.apache.org/jdo/pmf.html